# Why is 'gl_Position' a different data type than 'position'

Tags: opengl-es, webgl

I'm learning about GLSL shaders from code examples and I'm confused about the following thing: *gl_Position* is vec4 data type and *position* is a vec3 data type, why? what exactly is this 'position' variable and where can I find some kind of documentation on this? all I can find is gl_Position reference, same for gl_projectionMatrix vs projectionMatrix. *projectionMatrix* is not defined even in GLSL cheat sheets.

```
<script type="x-shader/x-vertex" id="vertexshader">

    varying vec3 col;

    void main()
    {
        col         = vec3( uv, 1.0 );
        gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
    }

</script>

<script type="x-shader/x-fragment" id="fragmentshader">

    varying vec3 col;

    void main()
    {
        gl_FragColor = vec4(col, 1);
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`position` is a user named variable. `position` has no meaning to WebGL. It might well be called `foo` or `bar` or `whatever`. It has no meaning to WebGL just like the variable `xyz` has no meaning in JavaScript

JavaScript

```
var xyz = 123;      // this has no meaning to JavaScript, only to the programmer
var position = 789; // this has no meaning to JavaScript either.
```

WebGL GLSL

```
attribute vec3 xyz;       // this has no meaning to WebGL
attribute vec3 position;  // this has no meaning to WebGL either
```

The same is true for `projectionMatrix`. It's a variable made by the programmer. WebGL doesn't care what the name is. If you're using a some library (like say three.js) that might make up some names for variables but those variables and the names chosen are part of the library, not part of WebGL. A Japanese programmer might use names like `haichi` and `shaeigyouretu` instead of `position` and `projectionMatrix`.

Variables that start with `gl_` are special global variables. There's a list of them on the [WebGL Quick Reference Card](https://www.khronos.org/files/webgl/webgl-reference-card-1_0.pdf). **ALL OTHER VARIABLES are made up by the programmer**.

> ## Built-In Inputs, Outputs, and Constants [7]
>
> Shader programs use Special Variables to communicate with fixed-function parts of the pipeline. Output Special Variables may be read back after writing. Input Special Variables are read-only. All Special Variables have global scope.
>
> ### Vertex Shader Special Variables [7.1]
>
> ```
> Outputs:
> Variable                   |Description           | Units or coordinate system
> ---------------------------+----------------------+------------------
> highp vec4 gl_Position;    |transformed vertex    |clip coordinates
>                            |position              | 
> ---------------------------+----------------------+------------------
> mediump float gl_PointSize;|transformed point size|pixels
>                            |(point rasterization  |
>                            |only)                 |
> ---------------------------+----------------------+------------------
> ```
>
> ### Fragment Shader Special Variables [7.2]
>
> Fragment shaders may write to `gl_FragColor` or to one or more elements of `gl_FragData[]`, but not both. The size of the `gl_FragData` array is given by the built-in constant `gl_MaxDrawBuffers`.
>
> ```
> Inputs:
> Variable                   |Description           | Units or coordinate system
> ---------------------------+----------------------+------------------
> mediump vec4 gl_FragCoord; |fragment position     | window coordinates
>                            | within frame buffer  |
> ---------------------------+----------------------+------------------
> bool gl_FrontFacing;       |fragment belongs to a | Boolean
>                            |front-facing primitive|
> ---------------------------+----------------------+------------------
> mediump vec2 gl_PointCoord;|fragment position     | 0.0 to 1.0 for
>                            |within a point (point | each component
>                            |rasterization only)   | 
> ---------------------------+----------------------+------------------
>
> Outputs:
> Variable                   |Description           | Units or coordinate system
> ---------------------------+----------------------+------------------
> mediump vec4 gl_FragColor; |fragment color        | RGBA color
> ---------------------------+----------------------+------------------
> mediump vec4 gl_FragData[n]|fragment color for    | RGBA color
>                            |color attachment n    |
> ---------------------------+----------------------+------------------
> ```
>
> ### Built-In Constants With Minimum Values [7.4]
>
> ```
> Built-in Constant                                 | Minimum value
> --------------------------------------------------+------------------
> const mediump int gl_MaxVertexAttribs             | 8
> --------------------------------------------------+------------------
> const mediump int gl_MaxVertexUniformVectors      | 128
> --------------------------------------------------+------------------
> const mediump int gl_MaxVaryingVectors 8          |
> --------------------------------------------------+------------------
> const mediump int gl_MaxVertexTextureImageUnits   | 0
> --------------------------------------------------+------------------
> const mediump int gl_MaxCombinedTextureImageUnits | 8
> --------------------------------------------------+------------------
> const mediump int gl_MaxTextureImageUnits         | 8
> --------------------------------------------------+------------------
> const mediump int gl_MaxFragmentUniformVectors    | 16
> --------------------------------------------------+------------------
> const mediump int gl_MaxDrawBuffers               | 1
> --------------------------------------------------+------------------
> ```
>
> ### Built-In Uniform State [7.5]
>
> Specifies depth range in window coordinates. If an implementation does
>   not support highp precision in the fragment language, and state is listed as highp, then that state will only be available as mediump in the fragment
>   language.
>
> ```
> struct gl_DepthRangeParameters {
>    highp float near; // n
>    highp float far; // f
>    highp float diff; // f - n
> };
>
> uniform gl_DepthRangeParameters gl_DepthRange;
> ```

As var as `position` being a vec3 that's also a programmer decision. It's just as fine being a `vec4` or a `float` or whatever you want it to be.

While a shaders can be anything you want and use any variable names you want probably the most common vertex shader is something along the lines of

```
attribute vec4 position;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;

void main() {
  gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * position;
}
```

Some programmers use `vec3` for `position` but then they have to coerce it into a vec4 anyway

```
attribute vec3 position;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;

void main() {
  gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1);
}
```

And since the `w` value of a vec4 attribute defaults to 1.0 there's no reason to do it manually.

[You might find these articles helpful in explaining WebGL](http://webglfundamentals.org/)

Comment: upvoted for being a very comprehensive and complete answer. This should be the correct answer.

Comment: It seems that `w` does some scaling (oddly lower than zero make the drawing larger)... Any idea why that would be included in `gl_Position`? Is it because it makes some matrix manipulation faster?

Comment: because when WebGL uses the value in `gl_Position` it divides by `w`. See [this](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-3d-perspective.html) and [this](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-3d-perspective-correct-texturemapping.html)

Answer (score 13):

`gl_Position` is a built-in vertex shader output variable, whose type is defined by the OpenGL specification to be a `vec4`.

`position` is a vertex shader attribute, and since the introduction of programmable shaders, **you** (as the developer) are in full control of its format.

Most likely, you have per-vertex 3D coordinates (hence, just 3 floats per vertex), that you configured as the vertex shader input via a call to `glVertexAttribPointer` (or similar), telling OpenGL to pull 3 floats at a time from a buffer for the `position` attribute. Since `gl_Position` wants 4 floats, the expansion to `vec4` (by filling in the `w` to 1.0) becomes necessary in the vertex shader.

Comment: Also good to note that threejs automagically prepends the position attribute (as a vec3) to your vertex shader if you use a ShaderMaterial. Might be the reason the OP was confused.